# Missing section links in table of contents (memoir class, custom section headings)

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir

I am trying to add a table of contents to a document produced using the memoir class. I have customized the section headings to emulate a publication I like. When I produce the pdf (using xelatex -shell-escape), the chapter-level and subsection-level hyperlinks in the table of contents work as expected, but the section-level hyperlinks do not. There is the appearance of a hyperlink for each section, but when I click on one, nothing happens.

Two constraints:

1. I need to stay in the memoir class.
2. The section (and sub-section) headings need to appear as formatted below (e.g., I don't want section numbering).

Two observations:

1. If I set the section numbering depth to 'section', the hyperlinks work as desired (but then I get numbered sections).
2. If I add \bfseries or any other series to  \setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase}, then the hyperlinks work (but again, I lose the formatting desired).

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{listings}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}                     
\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase} 
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape} 
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\small\bfseries}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter} 
\setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle                                                       

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\section{Another Section}
Text.
\subsection{Subsection 1}
Text.
\subsection{Subsection 2}
Text.
\section{Last Section}
Text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quickly fix the problem by defining your section heading style to include a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) anchor `\phantomsection`:

```
\setsecheadstyle{\phantomsection\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase}
```

Comment: Nice, works for the MWE. Now implementing in the full document . . .

Comment: I had to had `\phantomsection`'s to the `\setsubsecheadstyle` also. This worked well for me. Thanks.